# Find a bound for the function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, upper-lower-bounds

Consider $x, y$ real

> Find a **upper bound function** for
>
> $$\bigg |  \frac{x^3 y^4}{x^6 + y^6} \bigg |$$

I am trying to find an upper bound for this function, but have been unable to do so thus far.

How can I manipulate this using the triangle inequality?

Comment: Is it an upper bound or "upper bound function"? If the latter, define what that term means. Also you say $x,y$ real but $x=0=y$ is problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

Using the AM-GM inequality, we have $x^6+y^6\ge 2\sqrt{x^6y^6}=2|x|^3|y|^3$, which provides an upper bound of $|y|$.

Comment: good job ,Dr MV

Comment: @StuartMN Thank you!  My appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: you could use $\left(x^3-y^3\right)^2 \ge 0 \implies x^6+y^6 \ge 2x^3y^3$, so:
$$\left|  \frac{x^3 y^4}{x^6 + y^6}\right| \le \left|  \frac{x^3 y^4}{2x^3y^3}\right| = \ldots$$